# Why isn't the engraved effect action working for me [video] in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

So I'm attempting the same picture as this post claims to be able to produce, but I can't get the same output:

https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-engraved-illustration-effect-action-for-photoshop

**It should produce from this:**
[image]

**To this:**

[image]

**Video of the action:**
https://i.imgur.com/JM5vlTk.gifv

My result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you installed `.pat` file too? it's pattern file and it's core of action.if your photoshop missing patterns your output might gets totally messed :) so tell me do you have .pat files installed?? Edit: Tested action and it's working for me

Comment: It did have the .pat file, perhaps it's not compatible with cs6(13.0.1)? Not sure but following this video solved the problem for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9fcM2CWWPw

Comment: maybe .pat must be compatible but action might not. if your action contain some command which isnt available in cs then it should be trouble :)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I had a look at the .pat and the action. It would seem it works best on images that are around 3000px wide. Check the size of the image. It won't work well on small low rest images.

Comment: I tried on higher res photo to no avail, the youtube tutorial solved both the low and high res photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have `CS6 13.0.1` I believe it's missing some `action` commands.

Follow this youtube(has correct time): https://youtu.be/Z9fcM2CWWPw?t=306

Download the `.pat` file here: https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/freebies/Engraved-Effect-Photoshop-Action.zip

You'll have the patterns to start where the youtube link is.

Just add 6 layers and you should get the same effect from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: You have applied the action set to a low resolution screenshot, you must have a high resolution image to get fine enough lines. Check, how big pixel dimensions the engraving patterns have.

Not asked: The theory behind engraving effects is discussed in older cases. Here's one: [Create engraving in GIMP/Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99785/create-engraving-in-gimp-inkscape)

Comment: I tried the same action on a higher res photo but same result. Following the tutorial on the youtube link solved everything. The action just didn't work for me (CS6 13.0.1)